# Populate a ListBox with remote image

Tags: c#, image, xaml, listbox

I am using VS Studio Express 2012 on my Windows 8 machine and developing Win8 Store App, using a trial and free account.

I am using a ListBox in my app and try to populate an image with some other stuffs from a collection class. The code snippets look like this:

```
MainPage.xaml
<ListBox x:Name="OwnerDraw" Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Statuses}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="300" Height="400" Source="{Binding Path=photo.imageUrl}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="36" Foreground="Navy" Text="{Binding Path=id}"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="24" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Path=created_at}" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The id/created_at field displayed fine. But can't see the image.

The photo.imageUrl is something like: http://www.rsywx.net/books/cover/01732.png. The access to that site is OK and not down. A working example is [here](http://www.rsywx.net/books/cover/01732_%E9%93%B6%E6%B2%B3%E5%B8%9D%E5%9B%BD%E2%80%94%E2%80%94%E5%9F%BA%E5%9C%B0_%E9%98%BF%E8%A5%BF%E8%8E%AB%E5%A4%AB.png) for reference.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** It turns out to be working now. False alarm. Sorry!